# Cannot access my routers username/ password login box?

Tags: wireless-router

[image]When i enter my router's default gateway in any of my browser ( Firefox , IE , and Chrome) i get a "Login Incorrect" page but i cannot get the login box to enter the user name and password.

My all the browser versions are the latest and updated.

But when i access the same from a PC i get the login box not from my laptop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit : The PC where i am using the interface of login is connected through lan from the same router but from the laptop where i am trying to use the login interface is wifi from the same wifi router.

Comment: is your laptop forcing HTTPS, and your router does not have HTTPS enabled, and or is HTTPS enabled on router but not forced on laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your have stored login information on your laptop. How to clear it all depends on the browser.

Here's information for:

Chrome - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95537

FireFox - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-recent-browsing-search-and-download-history

And IE: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/delete-autocomplete-saved-information

Comment: And IE - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/delete-autocomplete-saved-information

Comment: I have tried that to but still the same.

Comment: After you have cleared that, have you restarted your browser? My next suggestion would be to clear all data from all browsers (including autocomplete data).

Comment: tried that too but still.

Comment: I see... If you have dumped all of your data, there should be nothing stored. It may be directing you to a cached copy. Make sure to dump ALL of your data (once more) and restart your machine.

Comment: after restarting its the same. I am running out of options now. ping is working fine though.

Comment: Here's something - you said you are able to connect via LAN but not via WiFi. Check your router settings for allowing people to manage the router remotely. Some routers (I know Linksys and Netgear do) have an option and you have to opt-in rather than opt-out.

Comment: How about after resetting your browser, also using CleanUp! 4.5.2 to clean up cached files to see if that will help?

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop seems to have stored logon info for the router.  You need to clear that from the browser.  Each browser will have a slightly different method of doing this but a quick Google search or use of Help will get you exact instructions.

Comment: can you please help me do that.